# Fast and efficient array lookup and modification

Tags: arrays, lookup

I have been wondering for a while which of the two following methods are faster or better.

### MY CURRENT METHOD

I'm developing a chess game and the pieces are stored as numbers (really bytes to preserve memory) into a one-dimensional array. There is a position for the cursor corresponding to the index in the array. To access the piece at the current position in the array is easy (`piece = pieces[cursorPosition]`).

The problem is that to get the x and y values for checking if the move is a valid move requires the division and a modulo operators (`x = cursorPosition % 8; y = cursorPosition / 8`).

Likewise when using x and y to check if moves are valid (you have to do it this way for reasons that would fill the entire page), you have to do something like - purely as an example - `if pieces[y * 8 + x] != 0: movePiece = False`. The obvious problem is having to do `y * 8 + x` a bunch of times to access the array.

Ultimately, this means that getting a piece is trivial but then getting the x and y requires another bit of memory and a very small amount of time to compute it each round.

### A MORE TRADITIONAL METHOD

Using a two-dimensional array, one can implement the above process a little easier except for the fact that piece lookup is now a little harder and more memory is used. (I.e. `piece = pieces[cursorPosition[0]][cursorPosition[1]]` or `piece = pieces[x][y]`).

I don't think this is faster and it definitely doesn't look less memory intensive.

### GOAL

My end goal is to have the fastest possible code that uses the least amount of memory. This will be developed for the unix terminal (and potentially Windows CMD if I can figure out how to represent the pieces without color using Ansi escape sequences) and I will either be using a secure (encrypted with protocol and structure) TCP connection to connect people p2p to play chess or something else and I don't know how much memory people will have or how fast their computer will be or how strong of an internet connection they will have.

I also just want to learn to do this the best way possible and see if it can be done.

### -

I suppose my question is one of the following:

Which of the above methods is better assuming that there are slightly more computations involving move validation (which means that the `y * 8 + x` has to be used a lot)?

or

Is there perhaps a method that includes both of the benefits of 1d and 2d arrays with not as many draw backs as I described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should profile your code to make sure that this is really a bottleneck worth spending time on.

Second, if you're representing your position as an unsigned byte decomposing it into X and Y coordinates will be very fast. If we use the following C code:

```
int getX(unsigned char pos) {
   return pos%8;
}
```

We get the following assembly with gcc 4.8 -O2:

```
getX(unsigned char):
    shrb    $3, %dil
    movzbl  %dil, %eax
    ret
```

If we get the Y coordinate with:

```
int getY(unsigned char pos) {
   return pos/8;
}
```

We get the following assembly with gcc 4.8 -O2:

```
getY(unsigned char):
    movl    %edi, %eax
    andl    $7, %eax
    ret
```

Comment: First of all you flipped x and y. It's x=pos%8 to get the x index in that row and y=pos/8 to get that row. I understand I could write a method but then that is even slower *and* I still have to do it a *lot* because when I check a bunch of positions to see if they contain a piece that can attack the king, for instance, I have to do two for loops like I would in a 2d array, but then for each index I also have to do over and over again the methods you wrote above.

Comment: Oh maybe you just name the methods incorrectly... getY returns x and the variable shouldn't be called x because it's confusing when you are returning y.

Comment: I fixed the X&Y names.  Gcc will almost certainly inline methods as short as the getX and getY here.

Comment: So I presume you are saying that the method I am using currently as described above (the one-dimensional array) appears faster.

Comment: Also, I want to learn assembly. How did you learn? I tried but very quickly gave up. Thanks for the breakdown, too.

Comment: I'm not sure which one is faster, because I'd have to measure the two approaches to be sure.  From the generated assembly, I'm confident that this approach is fast enough not to worry.

Comment: I can only offer two suggestions for learning assembler.  The first is, if you can, try to learn it on something with a cleaner instruction set than X86, like ARM.  Then learn X86.  The second is that I've found http://gcc.godbolt.org to be very useful for seeing how simple C constructs match up to X86 assembler.

Comment: Haha! I don't even really know C very well; just fiddled around with some Popen and other simple things. I started using Python after learning some other languages and I can't seem to pull myself out of the void. Every time I need to manipulate a lot of files or collect data or really walk to the store (just kidding), I use Python. It's just so freaking easy. If it's not Python, then it's bash.\ I guess I will learn C and then assembly. Thanks

Comment: oh wow! That is the best website I have ever seen in my entire life. I wish I could give you a hug. Thanks

Comment: you need `inline` to make it faster

Answer (score 1):

There is no short answer to this question; it all depends on how much time you spend optimizing.

On some architectures, two-dimensional arrays might work better than one-dimensional. On other architectures, bitmapped integers might be the best.

Do not worry about division and multiplication.
You're dividing, modulating and multiplying by 8.
This number is in the power of two, thus any computer can use bitwise operations in order to achieve the result.

- (x * 8) is the same as (x << 3)
- (x % 8) is the same as (x & (8 - 1))
- (x / 8) is the same as (x >> 3)

Those operations are normally performed in a single clock cycle. On many modern architectures, they can be performed in less than a single clock cycle (including ARM architectures).
Do not worry about using bitwise operators instead of *, % and /. If you're using a compiler that's less than a decade old, it'll optimize it for you and use bitwise operations.

What you should focus on instead, is how easy it will be for you to find out whether or not a move is legal, for instance. This will help your computer-player to "think quickly".

If you're using an 8*8 array, then it's easy for you to see where a castle can move by checking if only x or y is changed. If checking the queen, then X must either be the same or move the same number of steps as the Y position.

If you use a one-dimensional array, you also have advantages.

But performance-wise, it might be a real good idea to use a 16x16 array or a 1x256 array.
Fill the entire array with 0x80 values (eg. "illegal position"). Then fill the legal fields with 0x00.

If using a 1x256 array, you can check bit 3 and 7 of the index. If any of those are set, then the position is outside the board.
Testing can be done this way:

```
if(position & 0x88)
{
    /* move is illegal */
}
else
{
    /* move is legal */
}
```

... or ...

```
if(0 == (position & 0x88))
{
    /* move is legal */
}
```

'position' (the index) should be an unsigned byte (uint8_t in C). This way, you'll never have to worry about pointing outside the buffer.

Some people optimize their chess-engines by using 64-bit bitmapped integers.
While this is good for quickly comparing the positions, it has other disadvantages; for instance checking if the knight's move is legal.
It's not easy to say which is better, though.

Personally, I think the one-dimensional array in general might be the best way to do it.
I recommend getting familiar (very familiar) with AND, OR, XOR, bit-shifting and rotating.

See [Bit Twiddling Hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) for more information.

Comment: :) Actually, I did make a "valid move" array such that checking if a move is valid is as simple as `if validMoves[currentPos - selectedPos] in pieceMoves[pieces[selectedPos]]`. I *did* try to optimize other parts and I still am optimizing by looking at other people's code. This is Python2 by the way. Also, I made Pacman in Java as my first "major" project a couple years ago, so it's funny your name is Pacman--. Good link... bookmarked for C projects when  I start writing them. I shall also look more into bit-shifting and -rotating. I know a little from encryption but not much. Thanks so much!

Comment: `0 == ` is equivalent to just `!`, too probably; perhaps `0 == is faster`. (?)

Comment: The key to *real* optimization is not always to create the fastest code. Arranging your data in the best possible way is often overlooked, but essential. Your 'validMoves' lookup-table is a very good example on good optimization. -I would expect that you get the 'validMoves' pointer from looking up the piece in a table ? It's not easy to create a good chess engine, however, it's not easy to write a good Pac-Man clone either. ;) You might consider spawning threads to 'solve computer moves'. I think the number of ideal threads is approximately the number of CPU cores * 2.

Comment: Here is my code: https://github.com/dylnmc/chess/blob/master/chess.py ... If you search for `self.validMoves` you will find the instantiation and then how it is implemented if you keep searching. The code is actually pretty good, but checkmate and check checking (that's a lot of check) doesn't work right now, and I decided to rewrite everything. I don't know if you're up for looking at some Python code.

Comment: 0 == is exactly the same as !; however, I never use ! because in some cases bugs may arise from using it. I had the problem 25 years ago, where the code (!a && b) would not be equivalent to (b && !a).

Comment: You can look at my notes (https://github.com/dylnmc/chess/blob/master/validation_notes) to see why I decided to do it that way. Like I said; I tried to optimize; I'm just curious. If anyone sees any more optimizing, don't hesitate to criticize.

Comment: Python is something I try to avoid, whenever I can. ;) I prefer PowerPC and ARM assembly language, C, Objective-C, Perl and JavaScript, depending on the task, so reading Python is normally not easy for me. Remember when castling: King nor castle may move across a field that is attacked (many chess engines do not implement this correctly).

Comment: :)))) See comments on other answer. I got sucked into it after making a script for work. It's just too easy **not** to use it (I guess too easy to use it...). I'm going to try to write this in bash, C, C++ and Java, but I figured I would get my blueprints, if you will, laid out in Python. Also, thanks for the tip; I had that in my mind, but have not even fully implemented check-checking yet. I have played quite a bit of chess, too :D  Finally, I don't really know what PowerPC is, but I am about to google it. It sounds like it's for Windows although it's probably not.

Comment: ok; I guess powerpc is basically RISC... even though arm is RISC, too. I will just assume that they are very similar. Thanks for all your help; I don't want to tie you up.

Comment: Off-topic: PowerPC AKA. PPC, is the CPU used in the Macintosh before moving to intel. The PPC architecture is very similar to ARM - if you ever want to learn ARM code, I recommend getting an 'embedded board'; they're a lot of fun. For instance try searching for 'mbed'. On-topic: You may want to create a chess for embedded devices. ;)

Comment: From your "about me" page, it looks like you only know a couple languages ;)  I'm not sure I can trust your opinion; just kidding. Z80, too... that's what I tried to learn after only know Ti-basic for Ti-83 graphing calculator so that I could make calculator programs that were fast... that didn't go very well, and now I shudder every time I see Z80; I hope I can learn as many languages as you, though. Ok, I'm just talking now for no reason. Bye.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65330/discussion-between-pacman-and-dylnmc).